# Ratio of "proportional to" equations equaling each other

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-geometry, projective-space

I'm reading [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5419798/) and came across this section, which I don't completely understand.

[image]

Equations (19) and (20) are "proportional to" equations, where $LHS = k RHS$.

Equation (22) is formed using the following logic

$a \propto b$ (19)

$c \propto d$ (20)

$\frac{b}{d} \propto \frac{a}{c}$

$da \propto bc$ (22)

If $da = bc$ then we could easily say $da - bc = 0$. However, in this case, we have something along the lines of

$da = k(bc)$

so

$da -k(bc) = 0$

but not necessarily

$da - bc = 0$.

Since we are building a set of constraints for a homogeneous linear system there must be strict equalities on the equations. However, I'm not sure how this can be justified.

By the way $H_j$ mentioned in the paper is a homography matrix which is scale invariant, as in $H_j \equiv kH_j$. My guess is that since $H_j$ is scale invariant, we can just set $||h_{j1}^s||^2 = k = 1$.

Comment: I believe the point is that if $a\propto b$ then there is a constant $k_1$ such that $a=k_1b$. Similarly $c\propto d$ means that $c=k_2d$. In the context of the paper, perhaps the constants are equal, i.e. $k_1=k_2=k$, in which case $a/c = (kb)/(kd) = b/d$, so $ad-bc=0$.

Comment: Yes, this was my first thought as well. I can't think of a reason why $k_1 = k_2$ except for the fact that scale invariance of $H_j$ can allow $k_1 = k_2 = 1$

Comment: Actually.. now that I think of it, $h_{j1}^s$ and $h_{j2}^s$ are columns of the same matrix $H_j$ so their scale must be the same!